# How do I apply this css class

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble applying this CSS class. The `red-text` class is not being applied to my HTML. Why?

Here is the CSS:

```
<style>
.red-text {
  color: #FF0000
}
.green-text {
color: #00FF00
}
.dodger-blue-text {
color: #2998E4
}
.orange-text {
color: #FFA500
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<h1 class="red-text">I am red!</h1>
<h2 class="green-text">I am green!</h2>
<h3 class="dodger-blue-text">I am dodger blue!</h3>
<h4 class="orange-text">I am orange!</h4>
```

Why does the `red-text` not get applied?

Comment: Of course it does, how does the rest of your code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is not correct: it should not include `<style>` tags.

That's probably why you `.red-text` rule doesn't work: the browser is unable to parse the rule `<style>.red-style {color: #FF0000}` because it is not valid CSS.

Remove the `<style>` tags and that should work.

By the way, note that the browser is also unable to parse the last rule `</style>` of you stylesheet. But that doesn't impact anything and that's why the `.orange-text` rule works.

EDIT: It's even more interesting. The `</style>` tag is simply ignored by the browser, at least by Chrome. If you inspect this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pw434fmw/) with Chrome inspector, here is what you find:

```
<style type="text/css">
    <style>
.red-text {
  color: #FF0000
}
.green-text {
color: #00FF00
}
.dodger-blue-text {
color: #2998E4
}
.orange-text {
color: #FFA500
}
</style>
```

Strangely enough, Chrome is able to detect that the closing `</style>` tag shouldn't be there, but it is not able to do the same with the opening `<style>` tag. Note that if you mispell the closing tag as `</stylle>` for example, it is not removed by Chrome.

Comment: Thanks that was it.

Answer (score 3):

It's working. Are you using internal or external style sheet. If external means remove the `<style>` tag

```css
.red-text {
  color: #FF0000;
}
.green-text {
color: #00FF00;
}
.dodger-blue-text {
color: #2998E4;
}
.orange-text {
color: #FFA500;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="red-text">I am red!</h1>
<h2 class="green-text">I am green!</h2>
<h3 class="dodger-blue-text">I am dodger blue!</h3>
<h4 class="orange-text">I am orange!</h4>
```

Comment: Why not. I said you to remove the style tag. Check this working fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Prasathvkl/s9qpLvbv/)